# Selenium - Extract text in div without other tags (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to figure out how to access the text in the screenshot below without pulling all the `span` tags.

Doing `element = driver.find_elements_by_id('response')` gives me a list, but I can't seem to dig down further to access the text I want.

I also tried this after doing some searching:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='response']/pre")
```

But I get the same result.

Any tips?

[image]

Comment: *Doing `element = driver.find_elements_by_id('response')` gives me a list*  <--- Have you tried just `element = driver.find_element_by_id('response')`?

Comment: Yeah, that also gives me a long list with all the span tags.

Comment: Hmm...can you give us the link of that website?

Comment: Unfortunately none of this code loads until after inputting a bunch of fields, so won't really help

Answer (score 1):

element.get_attribute('innerHTML')

this will help you to get the text between two div tag

Answer (score 0):

```
element.text
```

Should give out the contents of the element without any HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the text being in the pure **div** the text is not extracted using `element.text`

Example:

```
<div>the text here</div>
```

I recommend to use a library called **html2text** and next:

```
html2text(element.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
```

It will do the trick!